# Word for Mac crashes on call from Javascript API

Tags: office-js

Executing the following code is causing Office to crash on OS X 10.11.6

```
 Word.run(function (context) {
     var docProps = context.document.properties;                                
     context.load(docProps);
     return context.sync().then(function () {
         console.log("ok")';
     });
 });
```

This gives the following error message in Office

> Microsoft Error Reporting log version: 2.0
>
> Error Signature: Exception: EXC_BAD_ACCESS ExceptionEnumString: 1
>   Exception Code: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS (0x0000000000000000) Date/Time:
>   2018-01-24 16:13:12 +0000 Application Name: Microsoft Word Application
>   Bundle ID: com.microsoft.Word Application Signature: MSWD Application
>   Bitness: x64 Application Version: 16.9.0.18011602 Crashed Module Name:
>   Microsoft Word Crashed Module Version: 16.9.0.180116 Crashed Module
>   Offset: 0x0000000001589a80 Blame Module Name: Microsoft Word Blame
>   Module Version: 16.9.0.180116 UnsymbolicatedChecksum:
>   06B178CD64DB4192894F984EBF0B6949 Blame Module Offset:
>   0x0000000001589a80 StackHash: 60a38d0df4d2bad-dm_1_main Application
>   LCID: 1043 Extra app info: Reg=en Loc=0x0413 Build Type: SHIP Crashed
>   thread Stack Pointer: 0x_00007fff58dbf860 Audience: Production
>   AudienceGroup: Production AudienceChannel: CC Crashed thread: 0
>
> Thread 0 crashed:
>
> 1  0x00000001083c6a80 in  (Microsoft Word + 0x0000000001589a80) 0x0000000000000000
>   2  0x0000000108396d23 in  (Microsoft Word + 0x0000000001559d23) 0x0000000000000000
>   3  0x0000000106f41805 in  (Microsoft Word + 0x0000000000104805) 0x00007fff58dbf8e0
>   4  0x0000000106f41240 in  (Microsoft Word + 0x0000000000104240) 0x00007fff58dbf9f0
>   5  0x0000000106f1da7b in  (Microsoft Word + 0x00000000000e0a7b) 0x00007fff58dbfad0
>   6  0x0000000106f1d231 in  (Microsoft Word + 0x00000000000e0231) 0x00007fff58dbfb60
>   7  0x0000000106f1c778 in  (Microsoft Word + 0x00000000000df778) 0x00007fff58dbfbe0
>   8  0x0000000106f1bdee in  (Microsoft Word + 0x00000000000dedee) 0x00007fff58dbfcc0
>   9  0x0000000106f200f4 in  (Microsoft Word + 0x00000000000e30f4) 0x00007fff58dbfd10
>   10  0x0000000106f27d02 in  (Microsoft Word + 0x00000000000ead02) 0x00007fff58dbff50
>   11  0x00000001083e7c04 in  (Microsoft Word + 0x00000000015aac04) 0x00007fff58dbffa0
>   12  0x00000001083e7085 in  (Microsoft Word + 0x00000000015aa085) 0x00007fff58dc0060
>   13  0x00000001083e6a81 in  (Microsoft Word + 0x00000000015a9a81) 0x00007fff58dc00c0
>   14  0x00000001083e60ab in  (Microsoft Word + 0x00000000015a90ab) 0x00007fff58dc0100
>   15  0x00000001083e5fd4 in  (Microsoft Word + 0x00000000015a8fd4) 0x00007fff58dc0120
>   16  0x00000001083e9108 in  (Microsoft Word + 0x00000000015ac108) 0x00007fff58dc0160
>   17  0x00000001078eccd5 in  (Microsoft Word + 0x0000000000aafcd5) 0x00007fff58dc0180
>   18  0x0000000107ec9a43 in  (Microsoft Word + 0x000000000108ca43) 0x00007fff58dc01c0
>   19  0x0000000107eca75e in  (Microsoft Word + 0x000000000108d75e) 0x00007fff58dc03c0
>   20  0x00000001084c204d in  (Microsoft Word + 0x000000000168504d) 0x00007fff58dc0420
>   21  0x000000010973acb9 in  (mbukernel + 0x000000000003acb9) 0x00007fff58dc0440
>   22  0x00007fff97808dec in ___NSFireTimer + 0x0000005F (Foundation + 0x00000000000a9dec) 0x00007fff58dc0460

This error started happening since very recent Office updates. We didn't experience any similar issues before. We also do not experience any problems on Windows.
Word version 16.9 (180116)

What we want to accomplish is reading the title property from the build in document properties from a taskpane addin. If there is a workaround that doesn't crash Word that would be very helpful.

Comment: We're aware of a similar issue and looking into it. Will post the update here.

Comment: Does this repro with a new blank document, or does it require specific properties to be set on the document? I was not able to repro using the same build of Office as you. Could you verify if there is also a crash executing the code you provided with Script Lab add-in on a blank document?

Comment: @Dan Saunders. This was tested on a blank document. I tried again today and the error and resulting crash still happen at my end.

Comment: @SudhiRamamurthy Is there any update on this issue?

Comment: @SudhiRamamurthy. It looks like this does work for us with Office version 16.14 (although that was tested on a different machine). On the same machine we still experience this error using version 16.12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be related to specific versions of Office. Although i have not yet received confirmation on this from Microsoft, this crash doesn't happen anymore with Office version 16.14.